# Eclipse is reading a Java char as Chinese

Tags: java, eclipse, cjk

I have two classes, one that writes a sequence of chars to a text file, and one that reads them. The writing part seems fine. It works, I can open the file and read the chars and it all looks normal. But when I try to read the file, it outputs to the console as a '?'. When I debug, it shows that the char is being read as a Chinese character. I switched my encoding language from the default (Cp 1252) to UTF-8, and that allows the console to read and display the Chinese character, but it still doesn't tell me why the English letter 'a' is being interpreted as the Chinese character for 'slow'.

Here is my code to write the chars to a document:

```
package iO;

import java.io.*;

public class WriteLetters
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        char[] letters = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g','h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n','o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u','v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
        System.out.println("Opening File...");
        
        
        RandomAccessFile randomFile = new RandomAccessFile("res/Letters.txt", "rw");
        
        System.out.println("Writing to the file...");
        
        for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
        {
            randomFile.write(letters[i]);
        }
        randomFile.close();
        
        System.out.println("finished writing");
    }

}
```

And here is my code to read and print them:

```
    package iO;
    
    import java.io.*;
    
    public class ReadRandomLetters
    {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            final int CHAR_SIZE = 2;
            long byteNum;
            char ch;
            
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("res/Letters.txt","r");
            System.out.println(raf.readChar());
            
            byteNum = CHAR_SIZE * 5;
            raf.seek(byteNum);
            
            ch = raf.readChar();
            
            System.out.println(ch);
    
        }
    
    }
```

I figured that I must have some language pack installed or some setting misconfigured that's doing this (though I could very well be wrong in that as well), but I don't remember having done anything for Chinese. So I would appreciate someone letting me know how I can fix this.

Comment: Well, this happens when you mix data types. You're writing as ints, but read them as chars. Either write and read as int or as char, but don't mix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> java.io.RandomAccessFile
> public void write(int b) throws java.io.IOException
> Writes **the specified byte** to this file. The write starts at the current file pointer

> java.io.RandomAccessFile
> public final char readChar() throws java.io.IOException
> Reads a character from this file. This method **reads two bytes from the file**, starting at the current file pointer.

You might want to try `writeChar`. Basically you currently write in a different encoding than you are reading. It tries to interpet the two bytes as a java char, which in this case results in a high codepoint character (something like chinese sign).